# Why is using a JWT Refresh token safer?

Tags: security, jwt

I'm implementing a JWT authentication system. Everyone is talking about how JWT access tokens should last just a few minutes and you should use a refresh token because it's safer that way.

I understand why it's unsafe to have a JWT access token that never expires, but what I can't seem to understand is why is using refresh tokens any safer?

You're storing the tokens at the same place, either in cookies or in localStorage and if the access-token is invalid, you create a new one with the refresh-token. So what stops the attacker from using the refresh-token instead of the access-token? How is this any safer? Am I missing something?

Comment: JWT does not perform any authentication.